# How to put data from Google Sheets to Timeline in web app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

I want to make a TimeLine chart based on data in the ["TimeLineData"](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SaGo-yA6YPP-Um68Sgm8H3yMyfqXclDQWl5_l4cxgs4/edit?usp=sharing) sheet. Those data will change sometimes so I want to make it dynamic. I am not sure if you can achieve it using regular charts so I have tried with script that I found in google documentation and then got help from @WhiteHat.

[image: This is my goal]

In the data sheet Column D and E are not necessary for this project. Only the colored columns.
As you can see on the picture I want to group orders by machines and to see time left to the end of production. Column F is showing how much time left in minutes. I also added extra cell for a start date H2 and I2.
From the left should be orders with the closest "Out for Delivery" date

So my problem is:

1. how to move data to the left? As you can see on the picture above. I want to make the same start point for all first values in a row and then add next time value. I've tried 'promise()' but coudn't make it.

This is what I am getting now:
[image]

Any advice will be helpful!
Let me know if something is unclear

The code provided by @WhiteHat:

```
   // load google charts
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['timeline']
}).then(function () {
  // get ss data
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SaGo-yA6YPP-Um68Sgm8H3yMyfqXclDQWl5_l4cxgs4/gviz/tq?gid=0&headers=1&sheet=TimelineData');
  query.send(function (response) {
    // build data table - ss
    var dataSS = response.getDataTable();

    // sort by machine, delivery date, order #
    dataSS.sort([{
      column: getColumnIndex('Machine', dataSS)
    }, {
      column: getColumnIndex('Out for Delivery', dataSS)
    }, {
      column: getColumnIndex('Order NO', dataSS)
    }]);

    // build data table - timeline
    var dataTimeline = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTimeline.addColumn('string', 'Machine');
    dataTimeline.addColumn('string', 'Order NO');
    dataTimeline.addColumn('date', 'Start');
    dataTimeline.addColumn('date', 'End');

    // get overall start date & time
    var startDate = dataSS.getColumnRange(getColumnIndex('start date', dataSS)).min;
    var startTime = dataSS.getColumnRange(getColumnIndex('start time', dataSS)).min;
    startDate = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate());
    startTime.forEach(function (timeSegment, index) {
      // determine time segment
      var milliseconds;
      switch (index) {
        // hours
        case 0:
          milliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * timeSegment;
          break;

        // minutes
        case 1:
          milliseconds = 1000 * 60 * timeSegment;
          break;

        // seconds
        case 2:
          milliseconds = 1000 * timeSegment;
          break;

        // milliseconds
        case 3:
          milliseconds = timeSegment;
          break;
      }

      // add milliseconds to start date
      startDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + milliseconds);
    });

    // process rows
    var endDate;
    var minutesProcess;
    var minutesTotal = 0;
    for (var row = 0; row < dataSS.getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
      // calculate minutes processed and end date
      minutesProcess = dataSS.getValue(row, getColumnIndex('Production Time Left', dataSS));
      minutesTotal += minutesProcess;
      endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * minutesProcess));

      // add row
      dataTimeline.addRow([
        dataSS.getValue(row, getColumnIndex('Machine', dataSS)),
        dataSS.getValue(row, getColumnIndex('Order NO', dataSS)),
        startDate,
        endDate
      ]);

      // determine if 8 hours has passed
      if ((minutesTotal / 60) >= 8) {
        // increment day until not the weekend
        do {
          startDate = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate() + 1, 8);
        } while ((startDate.getDate() === 0) || (startDate.getDate() === 6));
      } else {
        startDate = endDate;
      }
    }

    // determine chart height
    var rowHeight = 42;
    var options = {
      height: (dataTimeline.getNumberOfRows() * rowHeight) + rowHeight
    };

    // draw chart
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('timeline'));
    chart.draw(dataTimeline, options);
    window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
      chart.draw(dataTimeline, options);
    });
  });

  // get data table column index by column label
  function getColumnIndex(label, dataTable) {
    // loop columns until column label is found
    for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
      if (label === dataTable.getColumnLabel(i)) {
        return i;
      }
    }

    // label not found
    return -1;
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you know how wo put your data into your chart manually from the UI? If so, then please explain which kind of chart you want to use which data range, which options etc. - this will allow potential answerers to helpt you translate your request into code.

Comment: to draw the timeline chart, you will need a start and end date for each row. will you please elaborate how to calculate start and end date for each row in your data?

Comment: As a start date and time  I want to use H2 and I2 cell value. I want it to be the start for each row. As you can see on the picture, on the 0NCL63 row order N400682 starts at H2 and I2. That order needs 232min to be done so to 8AM you need to add 232min so it will be 11:52. And that time will be the start time for the next order which is N400622. Also I want to order it by the "out for delivery" date in B column and skip the weekends. I would like to set up a K2 as a hours in working day. For example when 8 hours will be added then the order after will go to the next day

Comment: @WhiteHat do you think it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the data to the page for use by the chart,
we can use the `Query` class.

append the query settings and sheetname to the end of the spreadsheet url...

```
/gviz/tq?gid=0&headers=1&sheet=TimelineData
```

use the query class to get the data and wait for the response.

```
var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SaGo-yA6YPP-Um68Sgm8H3yMyfqXclDQWl5_l4cxgs4/gviz/tq?gid=0&headers=1&sheet=TimelineData');
query.send(function (response) {
  // build data table - ss
  var dataSS = response.getDataTable();
  ...
```

then we need to process each row in order to build the start and end dates for each process.

first, sort the spreadsheet data...

```
// sort by machine, delivery date, order #
dataSS.sort([{
  column: getColumnIndex('Machine', dataSS)
}, {
  column: getColumnIndex('Out for Delivery', dataSS)
}, {
  column: getColumnIndex('Order NO', dataSS)
}]);
```

then build the data table for the timeline...

```
// build data table - timeline
var dataTimeline = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dataTimeline.addColumn('string', 'Machine');
dataTimeline.addColumn('string', 'Order NO');
dataTimeline.addColumn('date', 'Start');
dataTimeline.addColumn('date', 'End');
```

then we need to get the overall start date and time.
we can use data table method --> `getColumnRange(columnIndex)`
this will return the min & max values for the column we specify.
in this case, we'll use the min value.

```
// get overall start date & time
var startDate = dataSS.getColumnRange(getColumnIndex('start date', dataSS)).min;
var startTime = dataSS.getColumnRange(getColumnIndex('start time', dataSS)).min;
```

then we remove any time portion from the start date.

```
startDate = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate());
```

the format of the start time column will be [timeofday](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#working-with-timeofday)
it will be an array of four numbers --> `[hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds]`
we then add the start time to the start date.

```
startTime.forEach(function (timeSegment, index) {
  // determine time segment
  var milliseconds;
  switch (index) {
    // hours
    case 0:
      milliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * timeSegment;
      break;

    // minutes
    case 1:
      milliseconds = 1000 * 60 * timeSegment;
      break;

    // seconds
    case 2:
      milliseconds = 1000 * timeSegment;
      break;

    // milliseconds
    case 3:
      milliseconds = timeSegment;
      break;
  }
  
  // add milliseconds to start date
  startDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + milliseconds);
});
```

then we process the rows from the spreadsheet.
first, calculate the minutes processed for the row and calculate the end date.
add the data table row for the timeline.
finally, determine if 8 hours has passed.
if so, move to next week day, otherwise, use the end date for the next start date.

```
// process rows
var endDate;
var minutesProcess;
var minutesTotal = 0;
for (var row = 0; row < dataSS.getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
  // calculate minutes processed and end date
  minutesProcess = dataSS.getValue(row, getColumnIndex('Production Time Left', dataSS));
  minutesTotal += minutesProcess;
  endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * minutesProcess));

  // add row
  dataTimeline.addRow([
    dataSS.getValue(row, getColumnIndex('Machine', dataSS)),
    dataSS.getValue(row, getColumnIndex('Order NO', dataSS)),
    startDate,
    endDate
  ]);

  // determine if 8 hours has passed
  if ((minutesTotal / 60) >= 8) {
    // increment day until not the weekend
    do {
      startDate = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate() + 1, 8);
    } while ((startDate.getDate() === 0) || (startDate.getDate() === 6));
  } else {
    startDate = endDate;
  }
}
```

calculate the chart height, and draw the chart...

```
// determine chart height
var rowHeight = 42;
var options = {
  height: (dataTimeline.getNumberOfRows() * rowHeight) + rowHeight
};

// draw chart
var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('timeline'));
chart.draw(dataTimeline, options);
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
  chart.draw(dataTimeline, options);
});
```

see following fiddle for a working example...

https://jsfiddle.net/WhiteHat/cthqur2o/10/

Note: the chart will fill the width of the screen by default,
you may need to increase the width in the `options`

Comment: works perfect for me! But there is one problem.... On the spreadsheet I provided it works perfect but on the real spreadsheet it does not... I have no idea why... I think I put the link into a code correctly. The problem is that it shows nothing or this 'Invalid data at row #267: start(Sun Jul 25 2021 08:00:00 GMT+0900 (日本標準時)) > end(Sat Dec 26 2020 01:46:00 GMT+0900 (日本標準時)).' I guess it has a problem with formatting, because the real data are japanese format and the sample spreadsheet is polish format. I had no idea it might affect the code...

Comment: Also, I guess I wasn't so clear on that... H2 is a start date for each row so all machine rows should start at H2 and then just add the time of each order. I am sorry that I was not clear on that